# How to pass parameters in angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a function that does some error checkings and will be used in different input fields. My function code is below:

```
errorChecks = (element, minlength) => {
   if (element.$dirty) {
      if (element.$error.required == true) {
         this.errorMessage = "REQUIRED";
         return;
      } else if (element.$viewValue.length < minlength) {
          this.errorMessage = "MINLENGTH" // MINLENGTH error with parameters here
          return;
      } else {
          this.errorMessage = null;
          return;
      } 
   }
}
```

I am using the angularjs translate for my error messages.

```
"MINLENGTH": "{{ element }} must be at least {{ value }} characters",
```

I wanted to dynamically change my error message by passing a parameter to the translations like so:

```
errorChecks(username, 5);
```

If I enter 1 character to the username field the error would say: `username must be at least 5 characters`.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 72):

It'll probably be best if you translate inside the controller for this one, unless you want to pass `element` and `minlength` to the template.

Firstly you'll need inject `$translate` into your controller. Then to generate your message:

```
this.errorMessage = $translate('MINLENGTH', { element: element, value: minlength });
```

This method is also outlined [here](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Dynamize-your-translations#passing-values-through-translate-service).

To do this in the template (outlined [here](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Dynamize-your-translations#parametrizing-the-translate-filter)):

```
{{ MINLENGTH | translate : { element: element, value: minlength } }}
```

Comment: Your solution in the template didn`t worked for me. I had to remove the quotes.

Comment: template solution causes error, works only after removing the quites around object

Answer (score 19):

For anyone wondering how the syntax is, for using methods to retrieve the input for translation, this worked for me:

```
   {{ MINLENGTH | translate : { x: table.getShownCount(), y: table.getTotalCount() } }}
```

Answer (score 11):

This worked fine for me:

```
{{'commisionMessage' | translate : {fee:fee} }}|
```

Json File

```
"commisionMessage": "BLA {{fee}} BLA BLA"
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this in the template like this.

```
<span data-translate="MINLENGTH" data-translate-values="{ element: element, value: minlength }"></span>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `$translate.instant('MINLENGTH', { element: element, value: minlength })`